LinkedIn APIを使用してLinkedInユーザーのフォロワーを取得する方法は？
LinkedIn APIに関連する質問になります。
特定のLinkedInユーザーのすべてのフォロワーを取得するAPIはあるでしょうか？
組織IDのフォロワーすべてを取得するAPI(Organizational Page Follows API)はあったのですが、ユーザーのフォロワーすべてを取得するAPIが見つかりませんでした。
組織ページフォロー API
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/dma/pages-follows/organizational-page-follow?view=li-dma-data-portability-2024-05&tabs=http%2Cnon-obfuscated
